# How to send cookies on subsequent requests

Tags: javascript, rest, cookies, xmlhttprequest, jersey

I have a service running on a tomcat server that returns a `Response` object with `Set-Cookie` header set with a key-value pair. When i query that url directly by entering the service URL in the browser, the cookie gets stored and upon concurrent queries, the cookie info is sent to the server. Now, when i try to make that service request thro XMLHTTPRequest by providing that same URL, the cookie info is not stored. The js code is given below

```
 function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

The Header info is as follows

```
Request URL: url //removed the actual URL 
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.11.11:8080
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Content-Type, Accept, X-Json, Cookie
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Fri, 06 Sep 2013 10:04:49 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:key=value;Version=1 //removed actual cookie content
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

What am i missing here that makes the cookie go missing when requested thro XHR calls?.

Thanks in advance

Edit 1: I foundn out that in the second scenario (calling it thro javascript xmlHttpRequest), the cookie is not stored in the browser itself. Any pointers on why this might be happening. When i enter the service URL directly in the browser, the cookies are stored. Thro xmlHttpRequest, not stored. Is there something that I'm missing in either the Request or Response header?

Edit 2: Adding the Java class and the web.xml as well, so that there is more clarity.

```
package com.gk.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.CookieParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

@Path("/rest")
public class RestJersey implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Path("/response")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response sendResponse(@CookieParam(value = "userId") String userId ){
        return Response.ok("Something").cookie(new NewCookie("userId","cookie1")).build();
    }

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest creq,
            ContainerResponse cres) {
        cres.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        cres.getHttpHeaders()
                .add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                        "origin, content-type, accept, cookie, x-json");
        cres.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        cres.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        cres.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
        return cres;
    }

}
```

WEB.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RestJersey</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestJersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.gk.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.gk.rest.RestJersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestJersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Let me rephrase the title

Comment: Sorry, I made a rookie mistake. I was running the services on one server and the UI files on a different server, and the cross-domain-access played its part and dint allow me to store the cookie (which is something that i should i thought about in the first place). It worked when i opened the browser in --disable-web-security mode, and that gave away the fault.

Comment: Is there a way to close this question?. Thanks